# How to call the ItemSource of a DataGrid to refresh it?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am using would like to use WPF DataGrid to display a list of instances of e.g. a class `Animal` that I store during the life of my application (say I add/remove animals to my list) in an attribute of my main Window

```
public List<Animal> _animals
```

```cs
public class Animal {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public strng name { get; set; }
}
```

I added the `DataGrid` to my XAML as such

```xml
<DataGrid Name="AnimalGrid"></DataGrid>
```

Then linked it to a function `LoadAnimals()` when initializing my window :

```cs
AnimalGrid.ItemsSource = LoadAnimals();
```

```cs
public List<Animal> LoadAnimals() {
    return _animals;
}
```

I want the Data grid to update/refresh. More precisely I pretty much only want the data grid to call `LoadAnimal` function again. I have tried `AnimalGrid.Items.Refresh()`but it does not work.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: suggestion 1: do not manipulate UI elements in code. UI is not Data. Data is Data. UI is UI. suggestion 2: Learn MVVM. suggestion 3: implement INotifyPropertyChanged in your DataContext and raise it for the full collection if you want to reload it. suggestion 4: read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14381402/wpf-programming-methodology/14382137#14382137)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WPF bindings don't work by magic alone, the code somehow needs to emit the right events for the data grid to update.

To update in response to changes in the collection (additions / deletions), use `ObservableCollection<Animal>` as your `ItemsSource`, that will fire the proper events to update the data grid when the collection changes.

You will also have to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in your `Animal` class if you want the grid to respond to changes in the `ID` and `name` properties for the individual rows.

Also, your `LoadAnimals()` function doesn't seem to do anything, since it just checks for null and then returns null in that case. +1 for the comment about MVVM, it is better in the long run to bind your `ItemsSource` to some property in a class (view model) instead of setting it in the code behind.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only adding removing elements from collection. Then you can use [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx)

If you want to create a new collection or want to update properties of objects inside collection. Implement INotifyPropertyChanged.