# get set class not work in windows store apps

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

I created a new blank page xaml for windows 8 app. I have a textbox in the main page so the users can type their name in the main page. Also it has a button so that they can open new frame which is the blank page with the following codes :

```
this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(BlankPage1));
```

I made a get set class for the textbox so that they can see the value of the textbox in the blank page.

```
public string t1
    {
        get { return textbox1.Text; }
        set { textbox1.Text = value; }
    }
```

And these are the codes for the blank page :

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        MainPage p1 = new MainPage();
        textbox1.Text = p1.t1;
    }
```

But it won't show the value of the textbox in the blank page. It only shows **"TextBox"** in the textbox

Comment: Create a [ViewModel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14381402/wpf-programming-methodology/14382137#14382137) instead of trying to manipulate UI elements in code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're creating a new `MainPage` in the `OnNavigatedTo` - but you're not actually *showing* it.

You need to have a reference to the existing instance of `MainPage` - the one that's visible - not just some arbitrary new instance.

(As an aside, your `t1` member is a *property* - there's no such thing as a "get set class".)

Comment: I show it. I can see the textbox in the blank page. but it won't show me the value of the main page textbox

Comment: @aliboy38: No, you *don't* show the new instance of `MainPage` that you create in `OnNavigatedTo`. I've edited my answer a little having reread your question, but the fundamental issue is the same.