# Displaying a long table record in Gridview and various form controls combination with List

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-interface

My BLL return a list of something back to my UI:

```
List<ProductionParamater> l = BLL.GetProductionParameters();
```

The record contains around 42 fields. 5 of them i want to show them in a grid, and all the others i want to show them below the grid in a form-like appearence. Also i need to be able to edit them and send the changed list row back to bll for update.

My current structure uses a data access layer with datareaders to get the data. BLL executes the dal methods, applies the required logic and the results come back to the UI (Windows Forms).

I plan to hook on the grid events and update the rest of the form controls in every event fire-up. Also depending on the change i will send the list item back to bll to make the change.

Is this the correct way to go?

Comment: `Is this the correct way to go?` Yeh, of course go ahead! -- `Is this the better and easier way to go?` No, of course not. WPF is 100% more suitable for any kind of Master/Detail datacentric UI than winforms.

Comment: @HighCore ,yes i feel that but i dont have the time to go with WPF right now for this....My main concern is for my logic...

Comment: I fail to grasp how to make the whole application to be "binded" to the returned list and manage the updates...

Comment: there's a mindshift you need to have there. The UI is not "the whole application". The UI is just a visual piece of the application used to display the data to the user and let him interact with it. "the Whole Application" is the Data and the operations you perform on that data. Read [My Explanation here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14381402/wpf-programming-methodology/14382137#14382137)

Comment: To a lesser extent, because of the limitations of the framework, you could also apply these concepts in winforms.