# DialogResult contains no extension of '.OK'

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to let the user choose a folder, here is my code

```
using (var fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog())
{
    fbd.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer;

    DialogResult result = fbd.ShowDialog();

    if (result == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        //Code
    }
}
```

However, it appears that `DialogResult` contains no extension of `.OK`, I've looked around at some other questions, however none of them seem to work.

Answers tried:
[DialogResult.OK on SaveFileDialog not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23539219/dialogresult-ok-on-savefiledialog-not-work), [DialogResult with FolderBrowserDialog in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14813506/dialogresult-with-folderbrowserdialog-in-wpf).

I'm probably missing something very obvious...

Comment: You have a variable, member or class that's named `DialogResult`. Prepend the namespace.

Comment: Have you added the namespace? if not try System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann This is a WPF question.

Comment: @SirRufo Could you elaborate? From what I can tell FolderBrowserDialog is winforms (see also https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog(v=vs.110).aspx). Furthermore, when I tried his code, I had to add the System.Windows.Forms.dll assembly.

Comment: @SirRufo please fix the other unrelated changes, that you rolled back which are still valid.

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann Yes the dialog is WinForms and it is used inside a WPF application

Comment: @SirRufo I acknowledge that it is used inside a WPF application. I disagree with your opinion though. I think this should be tagged as Winforms.

Comment: @SirRufo, why do you put [Fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116101/299295) in question title?

Comment: @Sinatr I did not put anything into this question. I did only a rollback from a wrong edit. Check the history

Comment: @SirRufo, my bad, sorry. I'll keep comment with link for OP.

Answer (score 3):

You need to [add a reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh708954.aspx) to `using System.Windows.Forms;`. To do this:

> 1. In Solution Explorer, right-click on the *References* node and choose
>      Add Reference.
> 2. Find the `System.Windows.Forms` and then choose the `OK` button.

And then first add this to your `using` directive:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

And then:

```
using (var fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog())
{
    fbd.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer;

    DialogResult result = fbd.ShowDialog();

    if (result == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        //Code
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
MessageBoxResult result = MessageBox.Show("Your Message here", "Your caption", MessageBoxButton.YesNo, MessageBoxImage.Warning <= icon required, MessageBoxResult.No <= default result);

if (result == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
{
    return;
}
```

Comment: While this code might answer the question, it is usually considered good practice to add an explanation of what your code does. This allows for developers who are not knowledgeable in this area to understand what is going on in the code and helps them to learn how to solve the problem by them selves in the future.