# How to change ComboBox theme C# Windows 8

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

How to change custom ComboBox theme in WPF? I tried to change theme of whole application but my DerivedComboBox keeps using Windows 8 theme(it works good for normal ComboBox).
It works when I put DerivedComboBox into UserControl but I would like to avoid that.

Comment: what does your DerivedComboBox do? I can only image few (valid) reasons to subclass the WPF Controls.

Comment: I need to know LastSelectedItem.

Comment: That's a `Data` concept, it should be a responsibility of the ViewModel, not the View. That's not a valid reason to subclass the ComboBox. Create a proper ViewModel that knows what the last selected Item was, and operate against the ViewModel, not the View. [UI is Not Data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14381402/wpf-programming-methodology/14382137#14382137)

Comment: Yeah.. becouse your CB style has target type CB... you have to provide style with targetType DerivedComboBox, but you really should do what HighCore told you.

Comment: @HighCore There is no mention of the MVVM.