# WPF DataBinding not updating?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a project, where I bind a checkbox's IsChecked property with a get/set in the codebehind. However, when the application loads, it doesn't update, for some reason. Intrigued, I stripped it down to its basics, like this:

```
//using statements
namespace NS
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        private bool _test;
        public bool Test
        {
            get { Console.WriteLine("Accessed!"); return _test; }
            set { Console.WriteLine("Changed!"); _test = value; }
        }
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Test = true;
        }
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="TheTestingProject_WPF_.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
<Grid>
    <Viewbox>
        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=Test, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    </Viewbox>
</Grid>
```

And, lo and behold, when I set it to true, it did not update!

Anyone can come up with a fix, or explain why?

Thanks, it'd be appreciated.

Comment: Read [introductory material](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx).

Comment: I don't think I deserve a downvote because I read another source and not MSDN...

Comment: @ofstream I didn't downvote, but I suspect it's because this question doesn't show any research effort. This problem is extremely basic, and anyone who works with WPF's binding system knows that you need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` to make your properties notify the UI to reevaluate the binding when they get changed. Pretty much every single WPF tutorial that introduces bindings covers this concept.

Comment: That's exactly like saying newbs deserve downvotes because they don't know how to use basic methods. It's lack of knowledge. WPF is quite new to me.

Comment: @ofstream The downvote wasn't for your lack of knowledge, it was for your lack of research effort

Comment: You could aslo say that the newbs deserve downvotes because lack of research effort. MSDN + MSDN blogs have probably the answers to about 25% of all questions posted here, easily.

Comment: @ofstream: You are allowed to ask questions that are also covered elsewhere, but *only if it has not been covered here yet*. And as i said, this has been asked and thus covered way too many times before.

Comment: @H.B. OK, I get it now.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In order to support data binding, your data object must implement [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://wpftutorial.net/INotifyPropertyChanged.html)

Also, it's always a good idea to [Separate Data from Presentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14381402/wpf-programming-methodology/14382137#14382137)

```
public class ViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _test;
    public bool Test
    {  get { return _test; }
       set
       {
           _test = value;
           NotifyPropertyChanged("Test");
       }
    }

    public PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
         if (PropertyChanged != null)
             PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

<Window x:Class="TheTestingProject_WPF_.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Viewbox>
        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=Test, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    </Viewbox>
</Grid>
```

Code Behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new ViewModel{Test = true};
    }
}
```