# MVVM binding is not updating UI element

Tags: c#, mvvm, binding

In my .xaml I have a textbox "textBox_Input" that is bound to a string

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Button Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource LocStrings}, Path=ConnectDongle}" Command="{Binding ConnectDongleCommand}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="155" Height="21"/>
    <Button Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource LocStrings}, Path=ReadDongleFile}" Command="{Binding ReadDongleFileCommand}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="11,36,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="154"/>
    <Button Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource LocStrings}, Path=WriteDongleFile}" Command="{Binding WriteDongleFileCommand}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,63,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="155"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="textBox_Input" Text="{Binding Path=TextBoxInputText, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="170" Margin="10,90,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="218"/>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=TextBoxInputText, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="170" Margin="233,90,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="218"/>
</Grid>
```

The related ViewModel:

```
public RelayCommand ReadDongleFileCommand { private set; get; }
    public void ReadDongleFileCommandExecute()
    {
        TextBoxInputText += "a"; //this if just for testing
    }

    private String _textBoxInputText;
    public String TextBoxInputText
    {
        get
        {
            return _textBoxInputText;
        }
        set
        {
            _textBoxInputText = value;
        }
    }
```

When pressing the second Button bound to "ReadDongleFileCommand" both get and set of my TextBoxInputText are fired, so the command is working properly, but my TextBox is never updated. I never see any text in this TextBox.
I'm quite new to MVVM so probably I just forgot something simple, but I have no idea what it is.

Comment: Your view model should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and you need to fire `PropertyChanged` event in `TextBoxInputText` property setter

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17764323/how-to-bind-a-simple-string-value-to-a-text-box/17764545#17764545) SO thread for how to bind a property to WPF textbox.

Comment: Thank you, INotifyPropertyChanged was what I needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to raise a property changed event on your TextBoxInputText..

```
Public class YourClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public YourClass()
    {
        ReadDongleFileCommand = new RelayCommand(ReadDongleFileCommandExecute);
    }

    public RelayCommand ReadDongleFileCommand { private set; get; }
    public void ReadDongleFileCommandExecute()
    {
        TextBoxInputText += "a"; //this if just for testing
    }

    private String _textBoxInputText;
    public String TextBoxInputText
    {
        get
        {
            return _textBoxInputText;
        }
        set
        {
            _textBoxInputText = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("TextBoxInputText");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
    }
}
```

You probably want to look at the MVVM design pattern for more info [found here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx)

You will also need to hook your RelayCommand `ReadDongleFileCommand` up to the method `ReadDongleFileCommandExecute()` in the constructor of your class

Comment: Thank you, now it works. And thanks also for the link to the MVVM design pattern. Now I've something to read...

Comment: No problem. Could you please mark this answer as correct to complete the question.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at the [Binding.Elementname](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.elementname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Maybe you need to watch this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EpGvqVtSYjs&list=PLw8ap9mWnEiLOsVQhbEMQPiHC_xZqLcdQ) (one of 3), it helped me out allot.
Here is also a really great (and entertaining) [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q-yho2LfQ0Q&list=PLLh2p3Uip-bq_YfwTAg96SCcSC68M9IVz&index=2), it takes a different approach.