# Textblock binding text

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I want to display the string _lunedi in a textbox, the string _lunedi is updated periodically using InitializeBoxes().

I have my class:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
private string _lunedi= "lunedi ";
    public string lunedi
    {
        get { return this._lunedi; }

        set
        {
            if (value != this._lunedi)
            {
                this._lunedi = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("lunedi");
            }
        }
    }


    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

whit this method change the lunedi:

```
private void InitializeBoxes()
    {
        lunedi += todayPivot.Day;
    }
```

xaml:

```
<Border>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=lunedi, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBlock>
</Border>
```

The problem is that the text of the textblock is empty.
Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to bind a simple string value to a text box?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17764323/how-to-bind-a-simple-string-value-to-a-text-box)

Comment: How do you bind view-model to view?

Comment: I forgot to add  `DataContext = this;` but now only once updates the textblock.

Comment: Is NotifyPropertyChanged("lunedi"); triggered once InitializeBoxes method is called?

Comment: every time I change the state on lunedi, is called the set and triggered NotifyPropertyChanged("lunedi"), but only the first time going to change the text of the textblock..

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the binding is using one time try this instead

```
<Border>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=lunedi, Mode=OneWay}"></TextBlock>
```

Comment: sorry you should see it now