# Databinding textbox read from property

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to fill the text property from a textbox using binding. (My first try with binding).

I have this:

```
public string TestProperty { get; set; }

private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TestProperty = 'Test';
}
```

in xaml:

```
<TextBox x:Name="TextBox_Test" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="49,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="288" Text="{Binding ElementName=TextBox_Test, Path=TestProperty, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

The property is filled when the form loads. The textbox keeps empty. How can i fill the textbox?

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14965796/wpf-databinding-not-updating

Answer (score 0):

You've got to fix a couple of things before this will work.

First, you're binding expression isn't quite right. You specified that the binding source is the `TextBox` by using the `ElementName`. That's not correct. Your source should actually be the `Window` since that's where your property exists. So, give your `Window` a name, and change `ElementName` to that `Window`name. For example ..

```
<TextBox x:Name="TextBox_Test" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="49,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="288"
         Text="{Binding ElementName=Window_Test, Path=TestProperty, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Second, your `Window`needs to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`for changes on the source to be reflected on the target.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private string _testProperty;

    public string TestProperty
    {
        get { return _testProperty; }
        set
        {
            _testProperty = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("TestProperty"));
        }
    }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TestProperty = "Test";
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Note that I modified the class to implement the interface, and I raise the event in the property setter.

With these changes, your binding will work. I should note that this type of binding is a bit unusual. In cases like this, it's more common for the `Window` to use a `DependencyProperty`, or for you to bind to a non-UI class (A view model, for example). You may want to look into both as you learn about binding.

[Dependency Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-properties-overview)

[MVVM Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848246.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, it works. Is there a simple tutorial from the MVVM model?