# Listbox SelectedIndices of wpf window

Tags: c#, listbox, listboxitems

how can I use the following code on WPF Listbox Window . It works fine on normal Win form Listbox , so i wanted  test on WPF window, but im getting error saying

'System.Windows.Controls.ListBox' does not contain a definition for 'SelectedIndices' and no extension method 'SelectedIndices' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Controls.ListBox' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

this is the original code I have

```
 private void listBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            this.textBox1.Text = people[listBox1.SelectedIndices[0]].name;
            this.connectbox.Text = people[listBox1.SelectedIndices[0]].ipaddress;




        }
        catch
        {
        }
```

Comment: `It works fine on normal Win form Listbox ` - If you expect to just copy and paste code from winforms, WPF might not be for you. WPF requires a completely different mentality (MVVM) from the traditional, manipulate-ui-elements-in-code-behind mentality of winforms.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of what I mean by "WPF Mentality", which differs a lot from the archaic winforms mentality of mashing all together logic and UI:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.Window11"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Window11" Height="300" Width="300">
    <DockPanel>
        <Button DockPanel.Dock="Top" Content="Copy" Command="{Binding CopyCommand}"/>

        <UniformGrid Columns="2">
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" SelectionMode="Extended">
                <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=IsSelected}"/>
                    </Style>
                </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            </ListBox>
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItems}"/>
        </UniformGrid>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Code Behind:

```
using System.Linq;
using BaseWPFFramework.MVVM;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace WpfApplication4
{
    public partial class Window11
    {
        public Window11()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new ListViewModel();
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class ListViewModel: ViewModelBase
    {
        private ObservableCollection<Selectable<string>> _items;
        public ObservableCollection<Selectable<string>> Items
        {
            get { return _items ?? (_items = new ObservableCollection<Selectable<string>>()); }
        }

        private ObservableCollection<string> _selectedItems;
        public ObservableCollection<string> SelectedItems
        {
            get { return _selectedItems ?? (_selectedItems = new ObservableCollection<string>()); }
        }

        private DelegateCommand _copyCommand;
        public DelegateCommand CopyCommand
        {
            get { return _copyCommand ?? (_copyCommand = new DelegateCommand(Copy)); }
        }

        private void Copy()
        {
            SelectedItems.Clear();
            Items.Where(x => x.IsSelected).Select(x => x.Value).ToList().ForEach(SelectedItems.Add);
        }

        public ListViewModel()
        {
            Enumerable.Range(1, 100).Select(x => new Selectable<string>("Item" + x.ToString())).ToList().ForEach(x => Items.Add(x));
        }
    }

    public class Selectable<T>: ViewModelBase
    {
        private T _value;
        public T Value
        {
            get { return _value; }
            set
            {
                _value = value;
                NotifyPropertyChange(() => Value);
            }
        }

        private bool _isSelected;
        public bool IsSelected
        {
            get { return _isSelected; }
            set
            {
                _isSelected = value;
                NotifyPropertyChange(() => IsSelected);
            }
        }

        public Selectable(T value)
        {
            Value = value;
        }

        public Selectable(T value, bool isSelected): this(value)
        {
            IsSelected = isSelected;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Value != null ? Value.ToString() : string.Empty;
        }

    }
```

Just copy and paste my code in a `File -> New -> WPF Application` and see the results for yourself.

Notice that I'm using a generic solution (`Selectable<T>`), so you could use that with any classes you want.

Also, please don't do things like: `this.textBox1.Text = whatever` in WPF. WPF encourages the separation of UI and data, and you must understand that [UI Is Not Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14381402/wpf-programming-methodology/14382137#14382137) in order to properly work with WPF. Please leave the winforms mentality behind if you expect good results from WPF.

Instead, either create a proper ViewModel to hold the data shown in your textboxes, or bind the textboxes directly to an instance of the `SelectedItems` as in my example.

As an aside, off-topic comment, the `normal` way is not the winforms way anymore. All recent (`< 10 Years`) technologies (WPF, Silverlight, WinRT) are all XAML-based and encourage the use of MVVM.
This means that the winforms way is now the `old` way, not the `normal` way.