# How can I get the Position of textbox that has been pressed?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am writing in WPF the Sudoku Game and i make in run time 81 textboxes on canvas:

```
public partial class Test : Window
    {
        private TextBox[,] texts = new TextBox[9, 9];
        GameBoard board = new GameBoard();

    public Test(string path)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Initialization_text();
    }

    void Initialization_text()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < texts.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < texts.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                texts[i, j] = new TextBox();
                texts[i, j].Name = "txt" + i + j;
                texts[i, j].Width = 40;
                texts[i, j].Height = 40;
                texts[i, j].MaxLength = 1;
                texts[i, j].FontSize = 22;
                texts[i, j].FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
                texts[i, j].Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.DimGray);
                texts[i,j].TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;
                Canvas.SetLeft(texts[i, j], (i+1)*40);
                Canvas.SetTop(texts[i, j], (j+1)*40);
                canvas1.Children.Add(texts[i, j]);
            }
        }
    }
```

I need get the position of textbox that user is enter the number for checking the value, but i cant write the method that called TextBoxKeyDown because its make in run time

but if i write this method :

```
private void canvas1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (sender.GetType().Name == "TextBox")//the sender is canvas
            {

            }
        }
```

how can i get the textbox that user is enter the number?
pls help...

Comment: This is not the right way to do things in WPF. Don't create or manipulate UI elements in procedural code. Create a proper DataTemplate and use an ItemsControl.

Comment: i have this mission and i dont know wpf... not easy, thank you all for helping!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. Delete all your code and start all over.

This is how you do a Sudoku board in WPF:

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.Window17"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Window17" Height="300" Width="300">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid Rows="9" Columns="9"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style>
                <Setter Property="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding Row}"/>
                <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding Column}"/>
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Value}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" FontSize="20" TextAlignment="Center"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Window>
```

Code Behind:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace WpfApplication4
{
    public partial class Window17 : Window
    {
        public Window17()
        {
           InitializeComponent();

           var random = new Random();

           var board = new List<SudokuViewModel>();

           for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
           {
               for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
               {
                   board.Add(new SudokuViewModel() {Row = i, Column = j,Value = random.Next(1,20)});
               }
           }

           DataContext = board;            
       }
   }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
 public class SudokuViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public int Row { get; set; }

        public int Column { get; set; }

        private int _value;
        public int Value
        {
            get { return _value; }
            set
            {
                _value = value;
                NotifyPropertyChange("Value");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void NotifyPropertyChange(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));        
        }

    }
```

As you can see, Im in no way creating or manipulating UI elements in code. That's plain wrong in WPF. You must learn MVVM, and understand that [UI is Not Data. Data is Data. UI is UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14381402/wpf-programming-methodology/14382137#14382137)

Now, whenever you need to operate against the Value in the TextBoxes, just operate against the `public int Value` property in the ViewModel. Your application logic and your UI must be completely decoupled.

Just copy and paste my code in a `File -> New Project -> WPF Application` and see the results for yourself. This is how it looks in my computer:

[image]

**Edit:**

I have modified the sample to call a method when a Value is changed.

Please understand that you should NOT operate against the UI in WPF, but against DATA.
What you really care about is DATA (The ViewModel), not the UI itself.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System;

namespace WpfApplication4
{
    public partial class Window17 : Window
    {
        public List<SudokuViewModel> Board { get; set; } 

        public Window17()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var random = new Random();

            Board = new List<SudokuViewModel>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
                {
                    Board.Add(new SudokuViewModel()
                                  {
                                      Row = i, Column = j,
                                      Value = random.Next(1,20),
                                      OnValueChanged = OnItemValueChanged
                                  });
                }
            }

            DataContext = Board;
        }

        private void OnItemValueChanged(SudokuViewModel vm)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Value Changed!\n" + "Row: " + vm.Row + "\nColumn: " + vm.Column + "\nValue: " + vm.Value);
        }
    }

    public class SudokuViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public int Row { get; set; }

        public int Column { get; set; }

        private int _value;
        public int Value
        {
            get { return _value; }
            set
            {
                _value = value;
                NotifyPropertyChange("Value");

                if (OnValueChanged != null)
                    OnValueChanged(this);
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void NotifyPropertyChange(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));        
        }

        public Action<SudokuViewModel> OnValueChanged { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Comment: how can i get the textbox that pressed?

Comment: @LenaTrushevsky What do you want that for?

Comment: @LenaTrushevsky Please tell me what you need to do, and I can give you a way to do it. You don't really need to obtain a "reference" to the UI.

Comment: i need to check the value of the textbox that pressed. i want to use method public bool ChkLine(int line, string num) i need to get the line

Comment: @LenaTrushevsky You could change the `ItemsControl` to a `ListBox`, but still I don't understand what kind of method you want to execute.

Comment: @LenaTrushevsky Remember I told you you should operate against `Data` and not `UI`? You can place a method or event inside the `SudokuViewModel` class and call it whenever the `Value` property changes.

Comment: @LenaTrushevsky you are free to do it anyway you want, Im just telling you what's the RIGHT way to it in WPF.

Comment: for example : i need to check that number 9 do not repeat at this line. i need get the current textbox or whatever, for getting the current line for checking that number

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26186/discussion-between-highcore-and-lena-trushevsky)

Answer (score 0):

Use an attached event handler

```
AddHandler(TextBox.KeyDownEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(MyFieldClick));
```

this will get called for every text box inside the calling element. So if you place that in your window, every text box KeyDownEvent is patched through to the MyFieldClick event handler method. The sender is in this case the textbox that originally sended the event.

But i aggree with HighCore, you should utilize WPF more. In your case i see ItemControls and a Grid or better an UniformGridPanel.

Btw [TextChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.textchanged.aspx) might be the more appropriate event for your case.