# WPF MultiBinding TextBox Text programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, multibinding

I have a ComboBox in my View which the user choose a number of TextBox's to create dynamically.
each TextBox has an Index `i`, and I want to bind each of them to `array[i]`.
I searched for a solution and I found that I need to use MultiBinding with a converter.

How can I set a MultiBinding for a TextBox in my C# Code, and not in XAML ?
Thanks

**Edit:**
I am creating a grid of textBoxes, in order to create a matrix,
and I want to bind all of them to one array that will contain this matrix as a vector.
my code:

```
myGrid.Children.Clear();
myGrid.RowDefinitions.Clear();
myGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Clear();
int row = int.Parse(comboBoxRow.SelectedValue.ToString());
int col = int.Parse(comboBoxCol.SelectedValue.ToString());

for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
{
    myGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
}
for (int i = 0; i < col; i++)
{
    myGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
}

for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
    {
        TextBox tb = new TextBox();
        tb.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, i);
        tb.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, j);
        tb.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, "matrixArray[j + col * i]")
        myGrid.Children.Add(tb);
    }
}
```

So what do I need to write instead of: `"array[j + col * i]"`?

in ViewModel:
`public string[] matrixArray{ get; set; }`

Comment: It seems odd that you would want to bind a single textbox to multiple array items, you most likely want to bind to a single array item, so a multibinding isn't necessary.

Comment: I want to bind a single Textbox to a single array item, in order to bind it with array[i], I need a converter. I would be happy to get an alternative solution though.

Comment: Provide the code on how you're creating the textboxes. How is the index (i) exposed? The text binding can bind directly to the array instance. for example Text="{Binding array[0]}" With that being said, explain what you're trying to accomplish, there is probably a better way than the approach you're trying now.

Comment: No you don't need a converter, you can just specify an indexer on the binding. You only need a converter to change data being bound to.

Comment: Show the definition and initialization of the array property.

Comment: @HighCore I need it to be dynamically, do you have a suggestion how to do it using XAML ?

Comment: @MatanKri use an `ItemsControl`. Creating or manipulating UI elements in procedural code in WPF is a bad practice. Use XAML instead.

Comment: @HighCore Ok, could you give an example?

Comment: @MatanKri I've given tons of examples about this exact same thing already in SO. Perform a proper search. Otherwise post a screenshot of what you need and I can tell you the proper to do it in WPF.

Comment: @MatanKri see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15344546/643085)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should write something as follows:

```
tb.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, string.Format("matrixArray[{0}]", j + col * i))
```