# Nested UserControls DataContext

Tags: c#, wpf

***Abstract:***

I have two `UserControl`s named `Zone` and `ZoneGroup`. One of these controls (`ZoneGroup`) includes two instances of the other one (`Zone`). Both of them set `DataContext` of the root element to `this`, at the `Loaded` event-handler.

The problem is that `DataContext` of inner controls (`Zone`s) is set before loading (the `DataContextChanged` event occurred before `Loaded`) which causes some malfunctions in UI. (inside `Zone` controls initial state is wrong.) If I prevent it, everything works fine (at least seems to be!) except I encounter with the following error report. (In the Output window)

```
public partial class Zone : UserControl
{
    ∙∙∙

    private void Zone_DataContextChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Adding this if-clause solve UI problems but makes some binding errors!
        if (this.IsLoaded)
            brdRoot.DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'ZoneBrush' property not found on 'object' ''ZoneGroup' (Name='')'. BindingExpression:Path=ZoneBrush; DataItem='ZoneGroup' (Name=''); target element is 'brdRoot' (Name=''); target property is 'BorderBrush' (type 'Brush')

***Details:***

There is a `UserControl` named `Zone` containing several data-bindings like so..

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyApp.Zone"
    ∙∙∙>
    <Border x:Name="brdRoot" BorderBrush="{Binding ZoneBrush}" BorderThickness="1">
        ∙∙∙
    </Border>
</UserControl>
```

So, I set `brdRoot` data-context as

```
public partial class Zone : UserControl
{
    public Brush ZoneBrush
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(ZoneBrushProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ZoneBrushProperty, value); }
    }

    ∙∙∙

    public Zone()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Zone_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        brdRoot.DataContext = this;
    }

    ∙∙∙
}
```

Also, there is another `UserControl` that has two `ContentPresenter`s in order to contain and manage two `Zone` controls.

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyApp.ZoneGroup"
    ∙∙∙>
    <Border x:Name="brdRoot" BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding MainZone}"
                              Margin="{Binding MainZonePadding}"/>
            <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding MemberZone}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
</UserControl>
```

And the code-behind is:

```
public partial class ZoneGroup : UserControl
{
    public Thickness MainZonePadding
    {
        get { return (Thickness)GetValue(MainZonePaddingProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MainZonePaddingProperty, value); }
    }

    public Zone MainZone
    {
        get { return (Zone)GetValue(MainZoneProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MainZoneProperty, value); }
    }

    public Zone MemberZone
    {
        get { return (Zone)GetValue(MemberZoneProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MemberZoneProperty, value); }
    }


    public ZoneGroup()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ZoneGroup_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        brdRoot.DataContext = this;
    }

    ∙∙∙
}
```

---

Edit ► **Sketch:**
[image: Two zone controls in a zone-group control.]

My app works fine as expected, but some BindingExpression errors are reported.

Comment: This is all plain wrong. That's why it's malfunctioning. [UI is not Data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14381402/wpf-programming-methodology/14382137#14382137), therefore your `UserControl`s are not the right place to store data. Create a ViewModel instead and you will not have these issues.

Comment: @HighCore Would you mind please explaining more? What should I do exactly?

Comment: post a screenshot of what you need and what you currently have.

Comment: @HighCore This is my `View`. Zone controls should be put together in a group. Basic controls like `Zone`s have several DPs that are managed by container ones like the `ZoneGroup` control and so on. Finally, main container controls that have some `Model` relevant properties interact with the database using some intermediate class.  (my supposed ViewModel). Is this a good plan?

Comment: sounds ok, except for the fact that the `DataContext` of any given UI element should be its corresponding ViewModel, and not itself. Then if you need to bind to parent properties in the Visual Tree, use `RelativeSource` bindings.

Comment: also, a container that contains several items is an `ItemsControl`, and not just a custom usercontrol that has some properties.

Comment: Thanks a lot @HighCore :) I'll try to use an `ItemsControl` instead. Also I'll separate ViewModel class from View. Hope to solve this issue.

Comment: @HighCore, You said `DataContext` of any given UI element should be its corresponding `VM`. I read many posts, articles and some parts of several books about MVVM but couldn't find my answer :(  How can I have a `UserControl` inside another while both of them have their own `VM`? The container `UserControl` needs some of child `UserControl` DPs to control them. Unfortunately the story hasn't finished yet. There remained some other DPs that should be set directly in the container `UserControl`. what about them? (All `UserControl` DPs are placed in its `VM`.) Please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overcomplicating it all too much, with all those `UserControls` and all those `DependencyProperties`. Look at this sample which uses 0 lines of C# code (XAML-Only):

```
<Window x:Class="MiscSamples.ItemsControl"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="ItemsControl" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Window.Resources>
```

Style for the ItemsControl:

```
        <Style TargetType="ItemsControl" x:Key="ZoneItemsControlStyle">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ItemsControl">
                        <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                Padding="5">
                            <DockPanel>
                                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                           Text="{Binding Items.Count,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, StringFormat='{}{0} Item(s)'}"
                                           Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                           DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>
                                <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                        Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                                    <ItemsPresenter/>
                                </Border>
                            </DockPanel>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" IsItemsHost="True"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

DataTemplate For Brushes:

```
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Brush}">
            <Border BorderBrush="{Binding}" Margin="1" BorderThickness="1" Padding="2,3,2,3">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" TextAlignment="Center" Foreground="Black"/>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>

    </Window.Resources>
```

Now, its usage:

```
    <Grid>
        <ItemsControl VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                      Style="{StaticResource ZoneItemsControlStyle}">
            <SolidColorBrush Color="Red"/>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="Green"/>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="Black"/>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="Blue"/>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Result:

[image]

See how I'm making use of `DataTemplates` in order to show a custom piece of UI for a specific `Data Type`? (In this case, `System.Windows.Media.Brush` class)

I'm "using the Brushes as ViewModels". You could also create your own ViewModels of course, and then create a specific `DataTemplate` for each VM type.

Also, see how I'm using the `TemplateBinding` MarkupExtension to bind several properties inside the `ControlTemplate` to the corresponding value in the `ItemsControl` instance.

Finally, see how you can actually add `ANY` kind of items to the `ItemsControl`.

Also, I must mention that I used this `Style`-based approach in order to enable reusability. You could place another `ItemsControl` somewhere else in the application and set its `Style="{StaticResource ZoneItemsControlStyle}"` and you're done. But if you only plan to use this a single time, you can just place all the properties hardcoded in the `ItemsControl.Template` ControlTemplate.

Answer (score 1):

*This is not a direct answer!*

As @HighCore said, I tried to use an `ItemsControl` instead of implementing two `ContentPresenter`s in my user-control. Just for clarity I made a new simple app to be able to describe it simply. So please consider some new assumptions:

Here again, there are two `UserControl`s; `MyItem` and `MyItemsControl` as follows.

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyApp.MyItem"
             ∙∙∙>
    <Grid x:Name="grdRoot">
        <Border BorderBrush="{Binding ItemBorderBrsuh}" BorderThickness="1">
            <TextBlock x:Name="txtColorIndicator"
                       Text="Item"
                       TextAlignment="Center"
                       Margin="5"/>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

C# code-behind:

```
public partial class MyItem : UserControl
{
    #region ________________________________________  ItemBorderBrsuh

    public Brush ItemBorderBrsuh
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(ItemBorderBrsuhProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemBorderBrsuhProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemBorderBrsuhProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ItemBorderBrsuh",
                                    typeof(Brush),
                                    typeof(MyItem),
                                    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black), FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.None, OnItemBorderBrsuhPropertyChanged));

    private static void OnItemBorderBrsuhPropertyChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyItem instance = sender as MyItem;

        if (instance != null && e.NewValue is SolidColorBrush)
            instance.txtColorIndicator.Text = (e.NewValue as SolidColorBrush).Color.ToString();
    }

    #endregion

    public MyItem()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        grdRoot.DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

And this is the MyItemsControl.

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyApp.MyItemsControl"
    ∙∙∙>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock x:Name="txtHeader" Margin="0,0,0,5" TextAlignment="Center" Text="0 Item(s)"/>
        <Border BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1" Padding="5">
            <ItemsControl x:Name="itemsControl" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <local:MyItem />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </Border>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

C# Code-behind:

```
public partial class MyItemsControl : UserControl
{
    private ObservableCollection<MyItem> _Items = new ObservableCollection<MyItem>();
    public ObservableCollection<MyItem> Items
    {
        get
        {
            return _Items;
        }
        set
        {
            _Items = value;
        }
    }

    private void Items_CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        txtHeader.Text = Items.Count + " Item(s)";
    }

    public MyItemsControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Items.CollectionChanged += Items_CollectionChanged;

        this.DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

Here is how to use `MyItem` within `MyItemsControl`.

```
<Grid>
    <local:MyItemsControl HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="5" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
        <local:MyItemsControl.Items>
            <local:MyItem ItemBorderBrsuh="Green" Margin="1"/>
            <local:MyItem ItemBorderBrsuh="Red" Margin="1"/>
            <local:MyItem ItemBorderBrsuh="Blue" Margin="1"/>
            <local:MyItem ItemBorderBrsuh="Orange" Margin="1"/>
        </local:MyItemsControl.Items>
    </local:MyItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

Now, there is no problem with `BindingExpression`s, but an important question remains. How to replace

```
{
    grdRoot.DataContext = this;
}
```

and

```
{
    this.DataContext = this;
}
```

with a true `ViewModel`?

**Screenshot:**

[image: MyItemsControl]

---

***Edit:***  I tried to implement MVVM pattern but there are some problems. I asked the first one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15741515/nested-usercontrols-in-mvvm-with-different-dps-usage).