# adding elements to combobox from a list

Tags: c#, xaml, combobox, itemssource

My problem:
I have a listbox with owners of dogs, and i have a listbox with dogs. I want to modify the dogs listbox itemtemplate as the following: DogName(textblock)+DogKind(textblock)+Owners(combobox).The first two was successful, but i cant add the existing owners to the combobox. If i give a name to my combobox like :

```
<ComboBox x:Name="mycombo" />
```

i cant see the mycombo variable in the c# code.
The XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="CodeFirst.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:sajat="clr-namespace:CodeFirst"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="557.638" Width="721.294"
        >
<Grid x:Name="grid1"> 
<ListBox x:Name="listbox2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="313" Margin="338,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="250">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">                        
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text=", "/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Kind}"/>     
                        <ComboBox />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>     
</Grid>
</Window>
```

How can i give the itemsource to the combobox, or how can i reach to add the owners?

Comment: Consider using Converter, do not use 3 textboxes, use 1 only, and change the sole textblock's text with the formatted string or get it use a converter.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the DataContext, you can set the Binding like this:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.MyItemsSource, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}"></ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in order to work with WPF or other XAML-based technologies, you must understand that

[UI is not Data. Data is Data. UI is UI.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14381402/wpf-programming-methodology/14382137#14382137)

This means that you should not manipulate any `ComboBox` or any other UI elements in code, in order to populate them with data, but instead create a `ViewModel` and bind these objects to that.

In this example, the `Window` itself is used as `ViewModel` because it's a simple example, but you should consider moving all application logic to a separate class:

```
<Window x:Class="MiscSamples.UIisNotData"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="UIisNotData" Height="300" Width="300">
    <UniformGrid Rows="1" Columns="2">
        <DockPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="Owners:" DockPanel.Dock="Top" FontWeight="Bold" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="2"/>
            <Button Content="Add" Width="80" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Margin="2" Click="AddOwner"/>

            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Owners}">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" x:Name="block"/>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Visibility="Collapsed" x:Name="box"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListBoxItem}}" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="block" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="box" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </DockPanel>

        <DockPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="Dogs:" DockPanel.Dock="Top" FontWeight="Bold" TextAlignment="Center" Margin="2"/>
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Dogs}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <DockPanel>
                            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.Owners, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}"
                                      SelectedItem="{Binding Owner}" DisplayMemberPath="Name"
                                      DockPanel.Dock="Right" Width="100"/>
                            <TextBlock>
                                <Run Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                                <Run Text=", "/>
                                <Run Text="{Binding Kind}"/>
                            </TextBlock>
                        </DockPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </DockPanel>
    </UniformGrid>
</Window>
```

Code Behind **(This code should be placed in a ViewModel)**:

```
public partial class UIisNotData : Window
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Owner> Owners { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<string> Kinds { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<Dog> Dogs { get; set; } 

        public UIisNotData()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Owners = new ObservableCollection<Owner>
                {
                    new Owner() {Name = "Jack"},
                    new Owner() {Name = "Mike"},
                    new Owner() {Name = "Kirk"},
                    new Owner() {Name = "John"},
                };

            Kinds = new ObservableCollection<string>
                {
                    "Affenpinscher",
                    "Afghan Hound",
                    "Airedale Terrier",
                    "Akita"
                    //.. All the rest of dog Breeds taken from http://www.petmd.com/dog/breeds?breed_list=az#.UVsQKpPcmQo
                };

            Dogs = new ObservableCollection<Dog>
                {
                    new Dog() {Name = "Bobby", Kind = Kinds[0], Owner = Owners[0]},
                    new Dog() {Name = "Fido", Kind = Kinds[1], Owner = Owners[1]},
                    new Dog() {Name = "Toby", Kind = Kinds[2], Owner = Owners[2]}
                };

            DataContext = this;
        }

        private void AddOwner(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Owners.Add(new Owner(){Name = "New Owner"});
        }
    }
```

Data Model:

```
    public class Owner : PropertyChangedBase
    {
        private string _name;
        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set
            {
                _name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
    }

    public class Dog: PropertyChangedBase
    {
        private string _name;
        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set
            {
                _name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }

        private Owner _owner;
        public Owner Owner
        {
            get { return _owner; }
            set
            {
                _owner = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Owner");
            }
        }

        private string _kind;
        public string Kind
        {
            get { return _kind; }
            set
            {
                _kind = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Kind");
            }
        }
    }
```

**PropertyChangedBase Class**:

```
public class PropertyChangedBase:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

There are 3 important aspects you need to consider about this example:

- **I am in no way manipulating UI elements in code. That's completely unnecessary most of the time in WPF.**
- The classes from the Data Model implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in order to support 2-way binding in WPF.
- The Collections are of type `ObservableCollection<T>` in order to support automatic notification when elements are added/removed from the collection (in order to automatically update the `ListBoxes`, etc).

Another thing you may notice is that the XAML elements in my example have no specific size or `Margin` values. Things like `Margin="338,10,0,0"` is usually what you get from the Visual Studio designer and indicates a poorly structured layout. I recommend you look at the Layout elements in WPF (`DockPanel`, `StackPanel`, `Grid`, `UniformGrid`, `WrapPanel`, etc), and start coding the XAML yourself instead of using the designer. This will allow a much higher level of scalability and will also save you from the nuances of Fixed-position elements.