# WPF treeview to provide custom data entry views

Tags: wpf, view, treeview

New to `WPF` I am struggling to understand the concept of how to provide individual data entry forms based on a `TreeView` control.

In simple terms I have a window split in two columns, on the left I have a `TreeView` with static data as below

```
        <TreeView Name="treeView1" VerticalAlignment="Top"    SelectedItemChanged="TreeViewItem_Selected" >
        <TreeViewItem Header="Settings"  IsExpanded="True" IsSelected="True">
            <TreeViewItem Header="Status" IsExpanded="True" >
                    <TreeViewItem Header="Info"/>
                    <TreeViewItem Header="Connection"/>
                </TreeViewItem>
            <TreeViewItem Header="Settings" IsExpanded="True">
                    <TreeViewItem Header="Options"/>
                    <TreeViewItem Header="IP"/>
                </TreeViewItem>
             </TreeViewItem>
        </TreeViewItem>
    </TreeView>
```

I have the selected node information available in the code behind.

I require to have a form in the right hand colum which may consist of many different control, each view will be individual and shown depending on the selection from the `TreeView` `SelectedItemChanged`

I think I have issues understanding the context of templates etc, so I just don't know how to get this to work . I would have thought that as this is a mainstream model it should be quite simple, but starting to think this may not be the case, and should have used C++.

Any pointers and/or example code would be a great help.

Many thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but starting to think this may not be the case, and should have used
>   C++.

No, not really, the problem is that WPF requires a really different paradigm and "way of thinking" than most UI frameworks out there.

That's something called [MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14381402/wpf-programming-methodology/14382137#14382137)

Here's my take on what you described:

```
<Window x:Class="MiscSamples.TreeUI"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MiscSamples"
        Title="TreeUI" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding}" MinWidth="200" x:Name="TreeView">
            <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}"/>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        </TreeView>

        <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=TreeView}">
            <ContentPresenter.Resources>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:TreeViewModelBase}">
                    <!-- Empty -->
                </DataTemplate>

                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:SettingsViewModel}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding SomeSetting}"/>
                </DataTemplate>

                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:InfoViewModel}">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding SomeInfoText}"/>
                        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Infos}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ContentPresenter.Resources>
        </ContentPresenter>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code Behind (Boilerplate, just instantiating the hierarchy to support the example):

```
 public partial class TreeUI : Window
    {
        public TreeUI()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataContext = new List<TreeViewModelBase>
                              {
                                  new SettingsViewModel()
                                      {
                                          Children =
                                              {
                                                  new TreeViewModelBase()
                                                      {
                                                          DisplayName = "Status",
                                                          Children =
                                                              {
                                                                  new InfoViewModel(),
                                                                  new TreeViewModelBase() {DisplayName = "Connection"}
                                                              }
                                                      }
                                              }
                                      }
                              };
        }
    }
```

ViewModels:

```
public class TreeViewModelBase: PropertyChangedBase
    {
        public string DisplayName { get; set; }

        private List<TreeViewModelBase> _children;
        public List<TreeViewModelBase> Children
        {
            get { return _children ?? (_children = new List<TreeViewModelBase>()); }
        }
    }

    public class SettingsViewModel: TreeViewModelBase
    {
        public string SomeSetting { get; set; }

        public SettingsViewModel()
        {
            DisplayName = "Settings";
            SomeSetting = "This is Some Setting in the Settings section";
        }
    }

    public class InfoViewModel: TreeViewModelBase
    {
        public string SomeInfoText { get; set; }

        public List<string> Infos { get; set; } 

        public InfoViewModel()
        {
            DisplayName = "Info";
            SomeInfoText = "Welcome to the Info section!";
            Infos = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).Select(x => "Info Text " + x.ToString()).ToList();
        }
    }
```

Support Class (PropertyChangedBase)

```
public class PropertyChangedBase:INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action) (() =>
                {
                    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
                    if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
                }));
        }
    }
```

Result:

[image]

A couple of things to note:

- Each of these `TreeViewModelBase`-derived classes represents a "Widget". You could then add the relevant properties to store the actual Settings values on each.
- These are rendered into the Right part of the screen using the proper `DataTemplates` as shown in the XAML. You could also put each "Widget View" in a separate `UserControl` in order to keep the MainWindow.XAML clean.
- There's not a single event, or a single line of code that manipulates UI elements in my example. It's just *Simple, Simple Properties and `INotifyPropertyChanged`*. That's how you program in WPF. No need for `SelectedIndexChanged` or anything like that.
- In order to support Two-way binding, your properties must `OnPropertyChanged("PropertyName");`.
- Let me know if you need further assistance.

Comment: Thank you so much for your excelent answer and help, it is greatly apreciated. I now have a greater understanding of how this all works and will atempt tomorrow to do as you suggest and move the templates to user controls and attempt to create some actual data entry items. Am I correct in asumming the property items can be serialised and written as XML to save the current configuration status, as in settings. I only have been using WPF for the last 3 weeks and slowly understanding its model. Thanks again for the Help.

Comment: I created the View Models as UC located in a Views folder but I am unable to bind to them ?

Comment: @SarahT What do you mean exactly?

Comment: within the data template in the main.xaml I  have :               <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:ProfileViewModel}">
        how do I bind/reference the Views.viewProfileTemplate.xaml
</DataTemplate>. the template is a replica of your inline model for info ?. sorry again to ask Sarah

Comment: add an `xmlns:views="clr-namespace:YourNameSpace.Views"` in the root XAML element (Window) and then reference the UserControls by `<views:UserControlName/>`

Comment: Thanks for bearing with me .... I have exatly that but vs2010 reports the type Views:viewProfileTemplate was not found ..., but it does exist !

Comment: @SarahT Post a new question so we can continue there. Alright? =)

Comment: here is the header.  <UserControl x:Class="Configuration.Views.viewProfileTemplate"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d"