# Condition checking comboBox

Tags: c#, wpf

I need help catching a bug. Below is the provided code.

This is the controls for the form. When user closes the dropdown, form will automatically add in another row:

```
        private void addNewProfRow(object sender, EventArgs e) //all will invoke this generic method to display the visibility of the next
    {
        ComboBox selectedTest = (ComboBox)sender;
        Canvas thisRow = (Canvas)selectedTest.Parent;
        int index = Int32.Parse(thisRow.Name.Substring(thisRow.Name.Length - 1, 1)); //gets the num at the end of the name

        if (thisRow is Canvas && index == profMultipleCount && index < 9) //needs to ensure that only the previous canvas can invoke the next canvas once selection is done
        {
            profMultipleCount++; //points to the next row of canvas
            Canvas newRow = (Canvas)this.FindName("profileComp" + profMultipleCount); //finds the object and cast as Canvas
            newRow.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; //makes it visible

        }
        //hides the textBox in the case that user added a test component he did not want
        if (thisRow is Canvas && selectedTest.Text == "")
        {
            Canvas newRow = (Canvas)this.FindName("profileComp" + profMultipleCount);
            testComp = (ComboBox)this.FindName("testComp" + profMultipleCount);
            display = (CheckBox)this.FindName("profDisplay" + profMultipleCount);
            testComp.Text = "";
            display.IsChecked = false;
            newRow.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            profMultipleCount--;
        }
    }
```

And this is the method to save the user inputs.

```
        private void saveProfile(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int i = 1;
        Canvas newRow = (Canvas)this.FindName("profileComp" + i);
        testComp = (ComboBox)this.FindName("testComp" + i);
        while (testComp.Text!= "" && i < 10 && newRow.Visibility == Visibility.Visible) //order matters becoz newRow depends on i
        {
            //input the rowItem in the format (profileCode, testComp, displayable, action) of the excel sheet
            display = (CheckBox)this.FindName("profDisplay" + i);
            testComp = (ComboBox)this.FindName("testComp" + i);
            userData.setMulRowData(profileTab.Tag.ToString() + "," + (profileCodeCB.Text + "," + testComp.Text + "," + display.IsChecked.Value.ToString()[0]));
            Console.WriteLine(i + "," + (profileCodeCB.Text + "," + testComp.Text + "," + display.IsChecked.Value.ToString()[0]));
            i++; profileIndex++;
            newRow = (Canvas)this.FindName("profileComp" + i);
        }
        profileIndex++;
        clearProfile(sender, e);
    }
```

and my xaml is here:

```
<Grid Background="White" Height="3200" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Grid x:Name="panelTab" Height="410" Tag="Panel Component" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,0" IsEnabled="False">
            <Label Content="Panel Component:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Cursor="None" FontSize="16" FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol" Width="167" FontWeight="Bold"/>
            <Label Content="Panel Code:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="10,50,0,0"/>
            <ComboBox x:Name="panelCodeCB" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="134,54,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="85" IsEditable="True" Tag="Panel Code"/>
            <StackPanel x:Name="testCompList" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="274" Margin="10,92,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="361">
                <Canvas x:Name="comp1" Margin="0,0,8,0" Height="26">
                    <Label Content="Panel Component 1*:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                    <ComboBox x:Name="pComp1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="207" IsEditable="True" Tag="Panel Component" Canvas.Left="134" Canvas.Top="5" DropDownClosed="addNewPRow"/>
                </Canvas>
                <Canvas x:Name="comp2" Margin="0,0,8,0" Height="26" Visibility="Hidden">
                    <Label Content="Panel Component 2:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                    <ComboBox x:Name="pComp2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="207" IsEditable="True" Tag="Panel Component" Canvas.Left="134" Canvas.Top="5" DropDownClosed="addNewPRow"/>
                </Canvas>
            </StackPanel>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="496,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"><Hyperlink NavigateUri="C:\Users\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\User Upload\Data Upload\MainPanel.xaml"><Run Text="Add New..."/></Hyperlink></TextBlock>
            <Button Name="panelBtn" Content="Save and Add Another" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="418,344,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="135" Click="savePanel"/>
        </Grid>
```

When i do a writeLine for the user input, what i get is this:

1,tth,1
2,tth,2
3,tth,3
4,tth,

but what user actually typed is this:

1,tth,1
2,tth,2
3,tth,3

SO i like to ask how come my while loop does not restrict the empty row and still allows it to enter?

Edit:
when user does not close the last dropdown box, i get what user actually types, which is what i want, but i have no idea why is it like this.

Comment: Dude I don't know if you're aware of this, but there's a thing called [XAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Application_Markup_Language) which is normally used in WPF to define the UI instead of this bunch of horrible code. I strongly suggest you use that instead.

Comment: You really really really need to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14382137/643085) - I mean you said `I need help catching a bug`, but you really need help understanding how WPF is actually supposed to be used.

Comment: hi thx for the feedback but i do use xaml for my UI interfacing, just that validating is on my code behind and input gathering.

Comment: you got it all completely wrong. Your code is all wrong. and again, UI is not Data, therefore in order to validate stuff you should really do that in a ViewModel, not in the code behind by casting all elements like that. Please post a screenshot of what you need so I can tell you what's the proper way to implement it in WPF.

Comment: Put your `XAML` here.

Comment: hi it sounds like my codes is horribly wrong. Could you provide a simple way of how to implement correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Best to start over using a pattern like MVVM. There are numerous tutorials and books but I'll point one out to start with.

Chris Mosers has a nice [WPF tutorialsite](http://www.wpftutorial.net) start with his [explanation of MVVM](http://www.wpftutorial.net/MVVM.html).

It will be different to what you are used to, but in the end you'll be freed of the code you've shown. And no its not a 'simple way to implement', but if its a question of simple or good go for good.