# Programming a windows form in a mature way

Tags: c#

I am very new in C#. I have written a code to get two numbers in two text boxes and basically show their multiplication in a third text box.

The code is like:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double A = double.Parse(textBox2.Text); 
    double B = double.Parse(textBox3.Text); //gets the hourly wage
    double C = A * B; 
}
```

I have written them all in an executing button class. How can I get "A" and "B" in their own private texbox classes and relate them in "C" text box class?
I need to do it in order to validate the textboxes to give the user an error if he leaves any textboxes empty.

Comment: What you mean by `How can I get "A" and "B" in their own private texbox classes and relate them in "C" text box class?`

Comment: I can't get the point either. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Ain't the A and B are already related to "their own private textboxes"?, As you are getting A and B from textBox2 and textBox3

Comment: maybe we're not mature enough to understand :)

Comment: Probably this comment will get deleted, but I will go as far as to say that in you investigate what [MVVM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14381402/wpf-programming-methodology/14382137#14382137) is, you'll realize that winforms doesn't support "mature programming" and that you need more advanced and modern technologies for that.

Answer (score 0):

You may restrict user to fill in the text boxes before executing the button logic in this way:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(textBox2.Text == string.Empty || textBox3.Text == string.Empty)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid input");
        return;
    }

    double A = double.Parse(textBox2.Text); 
    double B = double.Parse(textBox3.Text); //gets the hourly wage
    double C = A * B; 
}
```

Comment: Personally I'd rather use `if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox2.Text))`, so it would check whitespaces too. But, I'm not really sure if this is the answer for this question.

Comment: @walkhard I just guessed it from the asker's statement "... I need to do it in order to validate the textboxes to give the user an error if he leaves any textboxes empty."

Answer (score 0):

This is what u do to display your answer in the third textbox

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(textBox2.Text == string.Empty || textBox3.Text == string.Empty)
    {
      MessageBox.Show("Please Fill Both Text Box");
      return;
    }

    double A = double.Parse(textBox2.Text); 
    double B = double.Parse(textBox3.Text); 
    textbox4.Text = (A * B).ToString(); 
}
```