# Creating a window that inheritate from an interface/abstract class and Window

Tags: c#, wpf, oop, inheritance

I'm creating a WPF application and I encountered a problem with the inheritance.
I have a class called `DataHandler` that make a link between GUI class and data class.
The code need to stay open, because the GUI or the Data part could change in the future, so the `DataHandler` use interface or abstract class reference to the real GUI/Data class.

For exemple, I have a `SelectionFrame` and it needs to use `SetSelection()` and `GetSelection()`, I created a `ISelectionGUI` interface that have both of the method.  and the `SelectionFrame`implements it.

```
public interface ISelectionGUI
{
    void SetSelection(HashSet<String> fields);

    void GetSelection(HashSet<String> fields);
}

 public partial class SelectionFrame : Window, ISelectionGUI
{
   [...]
}
```

In the `DataHandler` class it goes like this:

```
ISelectionGUI sF = new SelectionFrame();
```

But while doing this, I'm unable to use the `Window` method, except if I cast it like this:

```
((Window)sF).Show();
```

Wich don't seem to be the best solution since there is nothing that will force the next developer to extend `Window`.
I also tried to use an abstract class that extended `Window` and had the method that I needed. `SelectionFrame`extended that class and I changed the xaml [(following this)](http://mrpmorris.blogspot.fr/2012/08/partial-declarations-of-must-not.html):

```
<base:ISelectionGUI x:Class="WFChecker.SelectionFrame"
    [...]
    xmlns:base="clr-namespace:WFChecker"
    [...]
</base:ISelectionGUI>
```

But I didn't work since VisualStudio don't let me use an abstract class in the designer.
My question is: How do I manage to create a frame that implement a class or extends an abstract class, while still being able to access the `Window` methods ?

Comment: Just to cross check, your SelectionFrame Inherit Window class and implements ISelectionGUI? If so, please share complete structure of code.

Comment: @SumitGupta, yse it does, edited my post.

Comment: add a show method to your interface?

Comment: @TonyHopkinson, but that would mean adding every method I need from the `Window` class to the `ISelectionGUI`. I'm not sure this is a good way to go.

Comment: I am not very sure, but I recall in my projects I usually Inherit System classes in my custom Base Class, and then all Window and Form I develop, I inherit them from my base class rather than Window Class. It seems SelectionFrame here is PArtial Class [original window] instead make a BaseSelection, inherit/Implement all you want and then use that Base class as parent class to SelectionFrame. Hope that will sort it out.

Comment: Yep, You could get it to return a Window instead but then you would be locked in to that concrete type and have to cast to ISelectionGUI. Other option would be to go dynamic and unit test. Or you stop mixing your interface and class calls in one function with say some events, or other decoupling mechanism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing it all wrong.

You don't need to implement any interface in WPF UI elements because what you need is to use the [MVVM Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14381402/wpf-programming-methodology/14382137#14382137).

Instead of implementing that interface in the UI elements, create a proper ViewModel to hold your data and application logic and bind it to the UI via [DataBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx)