# WPF: property similar to WinForms Modified

Tags: c#, wpf, properties

In WinForms controls like a TextBox have property Modified that gets value "true" after changing the control's content and may be set to "false" manually. Their WPF analogues seem not to have such property (neither IsModified in new naming style). So do I have to handle their modifying events myself or there's some more convenient way?
For example I have few textboxes and a function, which combines their contents into one document for preview. Opening the preview I want to keep an old content for the document, if none of the textboxes was changed or to call the function to produce new document's content if at least one textbox was edited.

Comment: Thank you for quick reply, Coder. The variant with binding seems me too verbose (or maybe I don't know how to use it elegantly). I would like to get notification about the first change of one of the related controls and that's enough till the new preview would be generated. In other words I would like to have global property DataIsModified, which will become true, if some of the relative controls is edited, and will stop handling change events till setting it's value to "false". What can you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

In WPF it's easier to control everything through ViewModel/Model... This might be too much/not what you're looking for. But through experience, I feel that the pattern below pays off in easy usage.
Wrap your simple data class (with all the properties that it is using now/in your question now) in a class/Model that implements IEditableObject, INotifyPropertyChanged and possibly IEquitable. Lets call your class Data.
In a wrapper class create fields:

```
Data _current;
Data _proposed;
Data _previous;
```

IEditableObject requires you to implement BeginEdit(), EndEdit() and CancelEdit().
in them you need to control the state _current, proposed, and previous. For example,

```
public void CancelEdit()
{
   _current = _previous;
   _proposed = null;
}
public void EndEdit()
{
   _previous = _proposed;
}
public void BeginEdit()
{
    _proposed = _current;
}
```

You might need more logic in methods above, so this is just an example. The key of knowing if your object has changes is implementing a flag, lot's of people call it IsDirty:

```
pubic bool IsDirty { get { return _current != _previous; } }
```

Now the user of this class can easily check the state. Oh, and on more thing each property would have the following mechanism:

```
public string Example
{
   get { return _current.Example;}}
   set
       {
          if(_current.Example == value) return;
          BeginEdit();
          _current.Example = value;
          RaisePropertyChanged (() -> Example);
       }
    }
```

What's nice about implementing IEditableObject, all controls respond to it, DataGrid is a good example and also you can easily return to the original state by cancelling edit.
Anyway, there are lots of samples that you should browse for. I just hope to can get you started onto that path... 
P.S. this pattern was used before WPF came out, its super common in WinForms as well

Answer (score 0):

WPF doesn't have that because [UI is not Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14381402/wpf-programming-methodology/14382137#14382137) and therefore your UI is not the right place to store information about whether your data has changed or not.

Crappy dinosaur winforms doesn't allow a clean and true separation between UI and application logic/data and therefore has all sorts of horrible hacks in order to mash together these completely separate concepts.

You must learn to develop correctly, using the MVVM pattern. Then you will realize there's no sense in placing state data on any UI elements.