# UI does not update using binding XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a problem when UI does not update to changing in variables, that are binded to control properties.
Help me understand why.

1) I have a class which inherited from UserControl and from InotifyPropertyChanged

```
public class BindableControl:UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        #region Data

        private static readonly Dictionary<string, PropertyChangedEventArgs> eventArgCache;
        private const string ERROR_MSG = "{0} is not a public property of {1}";

        #endregion // Data

        #region Constructors

        static BindableControl()
        {
            eventArgCache = new Dictionary<string, PropertyChangedEventArgs>();
        }

        protected BindableControl()
        {
        }

        #endregion // Constructors

        #region Public Members

        /// <summary>
        /// Raised when a public property of this object is set.
        /// </summary>
        [field: NonSerialized]
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns an instance of PropertyChangedEventArgs for 
        /// the specified property name.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="propertyName">
        /// The name of the property to create event args for.
        /// </param>        
        public static PropertyChangedEventArgs
            GetPropertyChangedEventArgs(string propertyName)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName))
                throw new ArgumentException(
                    "propertyName cannot be null or empty.");

            PropertyChangedEventArgs args;

            // Get the event args from the cache, creating them
            // and adding to the cache if necessary.
            lock (typeof(BindableObject))
            {
                bool isCached = eventArgCache.ContainsKey(propertyName);
                if (!isCached)
                {
                    eventArgCache.Add(
                        propertyName,
                        new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
                }

                args = eventArgCache[propertyName];
            }

            return args;
        }

        #endregion // Public Members

        #region Protected Members

        /// <summary>
        /// Derived classes can override this method to
        /// execute logic after a property is set. The 
        /// base implementation does nothing.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="propertyName">
        /// The property which was changed.
        /// </param>
        protected virtual void AfterPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Attempts to raise the PropertyChanged event, and 
        /// invokes the virtual AfterPropertyChanged method, 
        /// regardless of whether the event was raised or not.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="propertyName">
        /// The property which was changed.
        /// </param>
        protected void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            this.VerifyProperty(propertyName);

            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = this.PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                // Get the cached event args.
                PropertyChangedEventArgs args =
                    GetPropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName);

                // Raise the PropertyChanged event.
                handler(this, args);
            }

            this.AfterPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        }
        #endregion

        #region Private Helpers

        [Conditional("DEBUG")]
        private void VerifyProperty(string propertyName)
        {
            Type type = this.GetType();

            // Look for a public property with the specified name.
            PropertyInfo propInfo = type.GetProperty(propertyName);

            if (propInfo == null)
            {
                // The property could not be found,
                // so alert the developer of the problem.

                string msg = string.Format(
                    ERROR_MSG,
                    propertyName,
                    type.FullName);

                Debug.Fail(msg);
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

2) Then I have another classes, each of them inherited from BindableControl like this

```
public class CameraLocalization : BindableControl
    {
        public CameraLocalization()
        {
            headers = new CameraHeaders();
            toolTips = new CameraToolTips();

            SetRuLocal();
            //SetEnLocal();
        }

        private Language lang = SettingsManager.Language.ru_RU;
        private CameraHeaders headers;
        private CameraToolTips toolTips;

        public Language Lang
        {
            get { return lang; }
            set
            {
                lang = value;
                SetLocal();
                RaisePropertyChanged();

            }
        }
```

3) In XAML I link this class as usercontrol and do binding like this:

```
    xmlns:language ="clr-namespace:SettingsManager.Localization.Camera"
     <Grid>
           <language:CameraLocalization x:Name="Localization"></language:CameraLocalization>
<GroupBox Header="{Binding ElementName=Localization, Path=Headers.PositionGroupHeader, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

4) from another page I try to change language:

```
    xmlns:language ="clr-namespace:SettingsManager.Localization.Camera"
<Grid Width="Auto">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Width="Auto" Margin="0,0,0,5">
            <language:CameraLocalization x:Name="Localization"></language:CameraLocalization>
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Language}}" Width="70" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                              SelectedValue="{Binding ElementName=Localization, Path=Lang, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></ComboBox>
```

And nothing happens. In debug mode i see that value of propertis changing, but they doesnot update on UI. What is the problem here? Who knows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your properties should  NOT be declared  in the UI elements (`UserControl`), and these should NOT implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. You must separate UI from data/logic by using the [MVVM Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14382137/643085).

You should create a proper ViewModel and put your properties and property change notification there.

Comment: Ok, but I want to bind properties wihout using datacontext and resources. How I can do this if I would not use userControl?

Comment: `but I want to bind properties wihout using datacontext` - Wrong. Bindings are resolved against whatever object is set as a UI Elements's `DataContext`. That's the way to do it. Not wanting to do so is like not wanting to depend on air to breathe.

Comment: The bad thing of using DataCOntext is that you cannot see for ex. Header of Control in VS editor before compiling - this is very uncomfortable and make XAML code navigation difficult. I already done variant binding via datacontext and it works greate, but are you sure that there is no other way to link class with XAML to use its properties in binding?

Comment: Noone cares about the Visual Studio Designer. If you really need that you will have to create `DependencyProperties` for all relevant properties in the UserControls. You must NOT implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in any `DependencyObject`-derived classes.