# SQL Connection WPF

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

So i m using this code for my sql connection to connect to local server :

```
public void ConnectToSql(string ServerName, string UserName, string Password)
        {
            string strConnection = "server=" + tbServer + ";uid=" + tbUser + "; pwd=" + tbPwd;
            SqlCon = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection();
            SqlCom = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand();
            SqlCon.ConnectionString = strConnection;
            SqlCom.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            SqlCom.Connection = SqlCon;

            {
                try
                {
                    SqlCon.Open();

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Failed to connect to data source");
                }


            }
```

I call it like this :

```
 private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ConnectToSql(tbServer.Text, tbUser.Text, tbPwd.Text);
        }
```

In windows form works perfect but when i try it in WPF gues what , cant connect to local server.
Any sugestions ??

Comment: WPF is a UI framework. It has NOTHING to do with SQL or whatever. By the way remove that horrible code from the code behind, and probably use an ORM, too.

Comment: You are probably going to have to give a little more information

Comment: Minimally use Trim().  I'm surprised that a commercial endeavour would permit db namespaces on the user surface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using the SqlConnectionStringBuilder, try something like this
as others said before WPF or WinForms has nothing to do with your Problem!

```
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand())
{
        cmd.CommandText = "Your Query"
        cmd.Connection = GetOpenDataConnection(".", "sampleDb", "sa", "12345");

        //Execute NonQuery or ExecuteReader
        cmd.Connection.Close();
}

private SqlConnection GetOpenDataConnection(string server, string database, string user, string password)
{
    var builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
    builder.DataSource = server;
    builder.InitialCatalog = database;
    builder.UserID = user;
    builder.Password = password;

    var connection = new SqlConnection(builder.ToString());
    connection.Open();
    return connection;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Quick solution:**

replace this:

```
string strConnection = "server=" + tbServer + ";uid=" + tbUser + "; pwd=" + tbPwd;
```

for this:

```
string strConnection = "server=" + tbServer.Text + ";uid=" + tbUser + "; pwd=" + tbPwd.Text;
```

**Correct solution:**

[UI is Not Data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14382137/643085). Learn MVVM before you write a single line of code in WPF. Don't manipulate UI elements in procedural code like that. Create a proper ViewModel and have your ViewModel access the DAL and expose the data and logic.

Also, you're better off using an ORM than ancient ADO.Net and putting all SQL instructions as `strings`.

And please, for Christ's Sake, remove that from the code behind and create a proper Data Access Layer.

Comment: @DaniDărăban [another link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Taking an educated guess your problem is probably on this line:

```
public void ConnectToSql(string ServerName, string UserName, string Password)
{
    string strConnection = "server=" + tbServer + ";uid=" + tbUser + "; pwd=" + tbPwd;
    //...
```

Rather than building your connection string with the parameters that are passed, you are using UI items, which probably don't build a very good connection string.  Try this:

```
string strConnection = "server=" + ServerName + ";uid=" + UserName + "; pwd=" + Password;
```

Also I agree with everything HighCore is saying, this is just a quick fix.