# TabControl Deep Copy

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, xaml, tabcontrol, deep-copy

I need to make a deep copy of a tabcontrol.

The large picture is this: I have a project which has a 300 line XAML code TabControl with 8 tabs in it which are pretty big. I also have a TreeView with different items.

When an item in that list is selected it shows the TabControl associated with it. The problem now comes that when I add an element I want to make a deep copy of the original TabControl and associate that new one to the new element (of course I'm going to erase the content in the new one). Shallow copies won't work because they are pointing to the same location in memory, so "=",IClonable are a no go. And the frustrating part is that I can't use deep copy with serialization because the TabControl is not serializable. And I can't (or should say won't) make a custom TabControl which is serializable because the TabControl is 300 line in XAML and it would be 600 line in code so it's a waste of space and time.

I've searched for this for 2 days and didn't find anything. There is no need for me to show the code because I'm looking for a general purpose Deep Copy method that can copy any type of a TabControl.

Comment: You really shouldn't be concerned with how much "space" 300 lines of code takes up. It won't make that much difference to the size of the application. Also, Please add formatting to your question.. for example, a new paragraph needs two "enter" presses (carriage returns)

Comment: How about using `Object.MemberwiseClone`?  There's an example on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.memberwiseclone.aspx) that shows using this to do both a shallow copy and a deep copy (the deep copy basically does a MemberwiseClone on the object, and then creates new instances in the cloned object of any nested reference types).

Comment: Tim I think I tried this ( I tried like 10 methods before asking here) but will try again.

Comment: Well I get this error: Cannot access protected member 'object.MemberwiseClone()' via a qualifier of type 'System.Windows.Controls.TabControl'; the qualifier must be of type 'Proiect_Design.Customize_New' (or derived from it) so basically it only lets me do a memberwise clone of my whole window or am I doing something wrong? I'm still a c# beginner..

Comment: @ChiriacDanAndrei - Yep, looks like it can only be applied to your whole window (unless you implement a custom TabControl).  You could do that quite simply - simply inherit from `TabControl`, and then add a DeepCopy method - you could then use `MemberwiseClone()` in your inherited control.  The only thing you'd be doing is adding the DeepCopy method - everything else would be provided by the base `TabControl` class.

Comment: Yes I know I can implement a custom tabcontrol but that defeats the purpose of my problem because I already have the tabcontrol defined in xaml so it would be double the size in c# code(aprox 600 lines in total). Of course if i had a custom tabcontrol it would be super easy because I could do as you said or marked it as serizlizable and be done with it but as I said I don't want to write the tabcontrol again in code.. And I can't use the custom one in xaml sadly( i tried that too :( )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching some more I initially tried a different way but it turned out to be more trouble than it's worth (tried with data binding and working more in code but still to much).

So the solution is to use XamlReader and XamlWriter. Official documentation is found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xamlreader.aspx) and respectively [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xamlwriter.aspx) !

To answer my question in code it would be:
Say you had this tabcontrol in XAML here:

```
<TabControl>
  <TabItem><!--A lot of stuff here--></TabItem>
  <TabItem><!--More stuff here--></TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

And remember this is if you have a lot of stuff (basically I didn't mention this but I'm making an interface that creates a pretty complex XML so in that TabControl I'm handling a lot of user generated data)! If you have a simple TabControl just make a custom one in code or simply use DataBindings.

So the code in the background for making a Deep Copy of that XAML defined TabControl would be this:

```
string savedTabControl = XamlWriter.Save(originalTabControl);

StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(savedTabControl);
XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader);
TabControl newTabControl = (TabControl)XamlReader.Load(xmlReader);
```

So this is basically serialization made on xaml controls and not on data.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it all wrong.

You're not supposed to "copy" the UI or whatever, because [UI is Not Data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14382137/643085). You should be manipulating and copying Data Items instead of UI elements, and probably using `DataTemplate`s to have your Data items represented on screen.

I strongly suggest that you research and learn MVVM before ever writing a single line of code in WPF.

Comment: Well thank you ! It is a start so I will research this model view view model you suggested. I really enjoy this do it yourself kind of answers because I'm not into taking shortcuts when learning new things.