# A switch expression or case label must be bool (or ...)

Tags: c#

Why this swich statement do not work, gives error:

> A switch expression or case label must be a bool, char, string, integral, enum, or corresponding nullable type

Code:

```
 switch (btn.BackColor)
 {
     case Color.Green:
         break;
     case Color.Red:
         break;
     case Color.Gray:
         break;
 }
```

Comment: What is the type of `btn.BackColor`?

Comment: I'm asking about the type of `btn.BackColor` specifically, not `btn`.

Comment: Have you tried defining a default case?  As well, does it compile or are you getting that error in compilation?

Comment: "System.Drawing.Color" type

Comment: I love these type of hacks. You're basically determining what to do based off a background color in a Button. EPIC. I feel a strong responsibility to tell you that [UI is Not Data](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14382137/643085)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error in in itself is self explanatory. it it telling you that switch expression must be ofone of these types: sbyte, byte, short, ushort, int, uint, long, ulong, char, string. or as the C# language specification suggests

> exactly one user-defined implicit conversion (§6.4) must exist from the type of the switch expression to one of the following possible governing types: sbyte, byte, short, ushort, int, uint, long, ulong, char, string, or, a nullable type corresponding to one of those types.

And you can see that BackColor is returning your a type here and it is not satisfying any of the above rules, hence the error.

you can do it like this

```
switch (btn.BackColor.Name)
{
   case "Green":
      break;
   case "Red":
      break;
   case "Gray":
      break;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The problem is you can't use a `Color` in a `switch` statement.  It must be one of the following types, a nullable version of one of the types, or or convertible to one of these types: `sbyte`, `byte`, `short`, `ushort`, `int`, `uint`, `long`, `ulong`, `char`, `string`

From the C# language spec, 8.7.2:

> • Otherwise, exactly one user-defined implicit conversion (§6.4) must exist from the type of the switch expression to one of the following possible governing types: sbyte, byte, short, ushort, int, uint, long, ulong, char, string, or,  a nullable type corresponding to one of those types.

In your case, you could work around this by using strings, or just using a set of `if`/`else` statements.

Answer (score 3):

You can't switch on `BackColor` because it's not an integral type.

You can only switch on integer types, enums (which are effectively integer types) and chars and strings.

You will need to find a property of `BackCOlor` that is unique (such as the `Name`) and switch on that.

Answer (score 2):

As the other answers have pointed out, `System.Drawing.Color` is not a usable type in a `switch` statement. `Color` is an interesting type because it behaves like an enum in code, but that is because it has a static property for each [`System.Drawing.KnownColor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.knowncolor.aspx), which is an enum type. So when you see `Color.Green` in code, here is what the `Color` class is doing behind the scenes:

```
public static Color Green
{
  get
  {
    return new Color(KnownColor.Green);
  }
}
```

Knowing this bit of information, you can write your code like this to use the `BackColor` property in a switch:

```
if (btn.BackColor.IsKnownColor)
{
    switch (btn.BackColor.ToKnownColor())
    {
        case KnownColor.Green:
            break;
        case KnownColor.Red:
            break;
        case KnownColor.Gray:
            break;
    }
}
else
{
    // this would act as catch-all "default" for the switch since the BackColor isn't a predefined "Color"
}
```