# Bind to a property of a collection declared in xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

There is a UserControl with the property - a collection of class Item, in Item is dep property Name. There ViewModel, property that needs bind to Name of Item. ViewModel is in the UserControl DataContext.

code:

```cs
public partial class UserControl1
{
     public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
...

public class Item : DependencyObject
{
     public string Name
     {
          get { return (string)GetValue(NameProperty); }
          set { SetValue(NameProperty, value); }
     }

     public static readonly DependencyProperty NameProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Name", typeof(string), typeof(Item), new     
     PropertyMetadata(null));
}

public class ViewModel
{
     public string Name { get; set; }
}

userControl.DataContext = new ViewModel { Name = "Test" };
```

```xml
<wpfApplication6:UserControl1 x:Name="userControl">
            <wpfApplication6:UserControl1.Items>
                <wpfApplication6:Item Name="{Binding Name, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,   
                 AncestorType=wpfApplication6:UserControl1}}" />
            </wpfApplication6:UserControl1.Items>
</wpfApplication6:UserControl1>
```

There is not work. Please, help me.

Comment: Same thing I tell everyone else: Learn MVVM before ever writing a single line of code in WPF. ObservableCollections don't belong in UserControls.

Comment: Because [UI is not Data](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14382137/643085). Therefore you shouldn't put Data into UI classes.

Comment: Item not Model class, is UI class. Like this `public ObservableCollection<DataGridColumn>`

Comment: What are you really trying to do? post real code.

Comment: Custom grid, with custom column collection, and bind column property from dataContext of grid

Comment: "There is not work" , can i quote you and that one ?

Answer (score 0):

```
       <wpfApplication6:UserControl1 x:Name="userControl">
            <wpfApplication6:UserControl1.Items>
                 <wpfApplication6:Item Name="{Binding Path=DataContext.Name, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,   
                      AncestorType=wpfApplication6:UserControl1}}" />
            </wpfApplication6:UserControl1.Items>
       </wpfApplication6:UserControl1>
```