# Serializing and deserializing System.Windows.Controls.UIElementCollection

Tags: c#, wpf

I am getting a **System.Windows.Controls.UIElementCollection** from a **System.Windows.Controls.Canvas** object in WPF, it contains a lot of **System.Windows.Shape** objects

What I am trying to achieve is to serialize these objects in the Canvas, then deserialize them later: like a save/load.

### Serialization code:

```
var items = view.myCanvas.Children;

var mystrXaml = XamlWriter.Save(items);
var fs = File.Create(@"C:\data.xaml");
var sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
sw.Write(mystrXaml);
sw.Close();
fs.Close();
```

### Deserialization code:

```
var sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\data.xaml");
var xmlReader = new XmlTextReader(sr);
var xamlReader = XamlReader.Load(xmlReader);
```

Serializing seems to be fine, while deserializing gives this error:

> No matching constructor found on type 'System.Windows.Controls.UIElementCollection'. You can use the Arguments or FactoryMethod directives to construct this type.' Line number '1' and line position '22'.

I conceptually understand that there are no parameterless constructors for **UIElementCollection** as it takes two parameters:

```
UIElementCollection(UIElement visualParent, FrameworkElement logicalParent);
```

#### How can I inject these parameters while the UIElementCollection is getting deserialized? Or am I going about this the wrong way?

Thanks

**Small edit:** the reason why I thought this was possible is because this library: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620154/UniversalSerializer seems to be able to cater exactly for this case, but I can't figure out exactly how it does it, there seems to be some reflection magic.

Comment: People should stop serializing the *UI*...

Comment: It's only very simple System.Windows.Shape objects. Do you have another suggestion that doesn't involve some Shape saver in a custom format?

Comment: Usually one should already have a data model backing the UI and serialize that instead.

Comment: WPF support MVVM, so create a Model for your shapes, use the Model to display the shapes, and then you can serialize/deserialize your model.

Comment: I save data to a `database` as I am creating the `UI` - properties and what not, then if I need to recreate it I build the `UI` based on the objects in the `DB`.

Comment: Learn MVVM before you ever write a single line of code in WPF. You don't serialize the UI simply because [UI is Not Data](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14382137/643085)

Comment: @HighCore Bit late for that! Though this is the first time I've mixed serialization with MVVM itself. Now I know!