# How get index rows which user is checked in DataGrid in Wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have DataGrid in Window and I put column inside the DataGrid type "DataGridCheckBox",and  I have button in the same Window, but the problem is I don't know how can get index all the rows which user is checked when user click this button.
the code is :

```
<Window x:Class="BenashManage.DeletePerson"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,0.4,-0.4" Width="546" >
  <DataGrid Margin="15,104,13.6,48.8" Grid.Row="1" Name="GridEdite" ItemsSource="{Binding Customers}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" AlternatingRowBackground="AliceBlue" Grid.RowSpan="2" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit="CellOrRowHeader"   >
     <DataGrid.Columns>
         <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding Path=delete}" Header="حذف البيانات"/>
     </DataGrid.Columns>
  </DataGrid>
  <Button Content="delete" Style="{DynamicResource BlueButtonStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Foreground="White"  Margin="211,328.2,0,9.8" Grid.Row="2"  Width="118" TextBlock.FontSize="20" Click="OnClicked"/>
</Grid>
```

behind code:

```
      private void OnClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
    DataGrid GridEdite = new DataGrid();

            foreach (DataGridViewRow r in GridEdite.*****Rows*****)
//in keyword Rows error "'System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid' does not contain a definition for 'Rows' " 
            {
                if (r.Cells["delete"].Checked)
                {
                    r.BackgroundColor = Color.Red; // or do something else
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: Create a proper viewmodel for the rows and handle this at the ViewModel level. [UI is not Data](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14382137/643085)

Answer (score 1):

Your `DataGrid` has an `ItemsSource` binding to a collection called `Customers`. Furthermore, your `DataGridCheckBoxColumn` column is bound to a `delete` property on these objects.

Within your click handler, simply search for the items in your collection which have this property set to true.

```
private void OnClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   var items = Customers.Where(c => c.delete);
}
```

Comment: when apply this code, I definition list name Customers but "delete" don't can access to this column Error "Error 'object' does not contain a definition for 'delete' and no extension method 'delete'"