# Binding an ObservableCollection to ListBox (Easy case?)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, observablecollection

I am *really* struggling to understand binding. I know there are loads of other threads with much the same title as this one, but they're all trying to do something more complex than I am, and all the answers assume a whole pile of stuff that I just don't get :(

I'm trying to display a dynamically updated message log. I've defined a Message class:

```
public class Message
{
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; private set; }
    public string Value { get; private set; }
    public int Severity { get; private set; }
    public Message(string value, int severity)
    {
        Timestamp = DateTime.Now;
        Value = value;
        Severity = severity;
    }
}
```

I've defined a MessageLog class as simply:

```
public class MessageLog: ObservableCollection<Message>
{
    public MessageLog(): base()
    { }
}
```

In my MainWindow constructor I have a Log property:

```
public MessageLog Log { get; private set; }
```

In the MainWindow constructor I initialise Log:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this;
    Log = new Model.MessageLog();
    // and so on
}
```

In the XAML for the main window I have:

```
<ListBox Name="MessagePanel" Height="100" ItemsSource="{Binding MessageLog}" IsEnabled="False"/>
```

Now if I add Message instances to the MessageLog I expected to see them appear in the ListBox. They don't. What have I missed?

Thanks in advance (and if you can point me somewhere that explains bindings *clearly* -- especially the view that XAML has of the code and where it can look for things -- then many more thanks on top. At the moment I'm using Matthew McDonald's "Pro WPF 4.5 in C#" and I'm just not getting it.)

Answer (score 0):

Change your constructor:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this;
    Log = new Model.MessageLog();
}
```

to this:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Log = new Model.MessageLog(); // <- This line before setting the DataContext
    DataContext = this;
}
```

---

**Explanation:**

Setting properties **after** having set the DataContext requires your class to implement [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) and raise change notifications after properties are set.

Since you're setting the DataContext **before** setting the property, the value of `this.Log` is `null` at the time of DataBinding, and WPF is never notified that it ever changed.

That being said, you don't usually put *Data* inside UI Elements (such as Window). The accepted and recommended approach to WPF is [MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14382137/643085), where you usually create a ViewModel and set that as the `Window`'s `DataContext`:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public MessageLog Log {get;set;}

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        Log = new MessageLog();
    }
}
```

Window Constructor:

```
public MainWindow
{
   DataContext = new MyViewModel();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your collection property name is **`Log`** which is what you *should be binding* to in `ItemsSource` property; and if you have not done a typo in your question then you are binding wrongly to `MessageLog`, and change `Binding` as below:

```
<ListBox Name="MessagePanel" Height="100" ItemsSource="{Binding Log}" IsEnabled="False"/>
```

For more information and learning on `Data Binding` in WPF (4.5), see [MSDN Data Binding Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The datacontext of the view must be the viewmodel.

Comment: The `DataContext` simply sets the data layer for the UI layer.  When following the `MVVM design pattern` I would agree with you that the `DataContext` should point to a `ViewModel`.  It would appear however that the OP is not following `MVVM` and therefore it is acceptable in this scenario to set the data layer of the view to thew XAMLs code-behind file.