# Accessing listbox items from DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite

I have a ListBox within a DataGrid. I've utilised an ObservableCollection to populate the ListBox Items. How do I loop over the ListBox items within each row? Please note that there will be more than one column containing ListBoxes.

Thanks In advance.

```
    public ObservableCollection<string> PotIncHazCollection
    {
        get { return _PotIncHazCollection; }
        set
        {
            _PotIncHazCollection = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("PotIncHazCollection"));
        }
    }
```

My UserControl is coded as...

```
    <DataGrid Name="dataGridJobSteps"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding}"                     
                      InitializingNewItem="dataGridJobSteps_InitializingNewItem"
                      AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                      CanUserSortColumns="True"
                      SelectionMode="Single"
                      CanUserReorderColumns="True"
                      CanUserResizeColumns="True"
                      VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                      Height="Auto" Width="Auto" FontWeight="Normal">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="JobSafetyAnalysisStepID" Binding="{Binding Path=JobSafetyAnalysisStepID}" Visibility="Hidden" />
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Step #" Binding="{Binding Path=StepNumber}" />

                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Description of Job Steps" Width="200">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=StepDescription}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=StepDescription}" TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Height="50" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>                        
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Potential Incidents or Hazards" Width="200">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding PotIncHazCollection}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <!--<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=selectedPotentialHazardPotentialHazard}" TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Height="50" />-->
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Controls and Checks Required" Width="200">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ControlsChecksCollection}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <!--<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=selectedPotentialHazardPotentialHazard}" TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Height="50" />-->
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Actioned By" Width="200">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ActionedByCollection}" />
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <!--<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=selectedPotentialHazardPotentialHazard}" TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Height="50" />-->
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

My Code Behind to populate the DataGrid Rows and ListBox items is...

```
            private void getJSAStepDetail()
    {
        try
        {
            DataTable jobSteps;
            String query = "select JobSafetyAnalysisStepPotentialHazardID \"JobSafetyAnalysisStepPotentialHazardID\""
                + ", StepDescription \"StepDescription\""
                + ", StepNumber \"StepNumber\""
                + ", RefJobSafetyAnalysisStepID \"RefJobSafetyAnalysisStepID\""
                + " from JobSafetyAnalysisPotentialHazard_view"
                + " where RefPermitID = '" + thisRefPermitID + "' Group by RefJobSafetyAnalysisStepID";

            jobSteps = db.GetDataTable(query);

            List<JobSafetyAnalysisData> jobStepItems = new List<JobSafetyAnalysisData>();

            foreach (DataRow r in jobSteps.Rows)
            {
                if (jobStepItems != null)
                {
                    string refStepId = r["RefJobSafetyAnalysisStepID"].ToString();

                    String potHazQuery = "select PotentialHazard from JobSafetyAnalysisPotentialHazard_view where RefJobSafetyAnalysisStepID = '" + refStepId + "'";
                    DataTable refSteps = db.GetDataTable(potHazQuery);

                    ObservableCollection<string> colRefSteps = new ObservableCollection<string>();

                    foreach (DataRow refStepsRow in refSteps.Rows)
                    {
                        colRefSteps.Add(refStepsRow["PotentialHazard"].ToString());
                    }

                    jobStepItems.Add(new JobSafetyAnalysisData()
                    {
                        JobSafetyAnalysisStepID = r["RefJobSafetyAnalysisStepID"].ToString(),
                        StepNumber = r["StepNumber"].ToString(),
                        StepDescription = r["StepDescription"].ToString(),
                        PotIncHazCollection = colRefSteps
                    });
                }
            }               

            dataGridJobSteps.ItemsSource = jobStepItems;
        }
        catch (Exception fail)
        {
            String error = "The following error has occurred:\n\n";
            error += fail.Message.ToString() + "\n\n";
            MessageBox.Show(error);
        }
    }
```

OK got the above sorted by below code but it's only iterating the first column ListBox (great) but there are two other column data items that I need to get values from...

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Update Job Step Grid ListBox
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridJobSteps.Items.Count; i++)
        {                
            DependencyObject obj = dataGridJobSteps.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i);
            ListBox _listBox = FindVisualChild<ListBox>(obj);

            var selectedItems = _listBox.Items;
            foreach (var selectedItem in selectedItems)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(selectedItem.ToString());
            }
        }
    }

    public static childItem FindVisualChild<childItem>(DependencyObject obj) where childItem : DependencyObject
    {
        // Search immediate children
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(obj); i++)
        {
            DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(obj, i);

            if (child is childItem)
                return (childItem)child;

            else
            {
                childItem childOfChild = FindVisualChild<childItem>(child);

                if (childOfChild != null)
                    return childOfChild;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: `How do I loop over the ListBox items within each row` - You don't "loop" over the UI in WPF, because [UI is not Data](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14382137/643085). Iterate over your data items instead. And please, for God's sake, use an ORM, or otherwise remove that horrible SQL string stuff from your ViewModels.

Comment: Yes, will do... still finding my way around wpf/MVVM etc.

thanks HighCore