# Creating text files with specific names

Tags: c#, wpf

Hello I would like to ask how I can create a text file with a specific name and gain access to the folder I'am saving into since I'am the administrator of the computer but I do not have access to save through C#.
What i would like to do is iterate over buttons in a UI and get the names of the buttons and write them as text file names in a directory.

I would enjoy getting an answer how I can modify the name of the file I'am saving.
My code so far looks like this.

```
 foreach (Button bt in mainCanvasGrid.Children)
{
   File.WriteAllLines()
}
```

Comment: just put a string variable and change it in each iteraton. What have you tried?

Comment: I tried WriteAllLines() because I know it creates a file each time and this is exactly the behaviour I'm looking for - to create a file with the name of each button as the file name,but I cannot modify the name of the file I'm creating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just put a string variable and change it in each iteraton:

```
var myfile = @"C:\myfile"
foreach (Button bt in mainCanvasGrid.Children)
{
   File.WriteAllLines(myfile + bt.Name + ".txt", new []{"[yourtexthere]"});
}
```

BTW, the preferred approach to WPF is [MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14382137/643085). You don't "iterate a collection of Buttons" in the UI simply because **UI is NOT Data**. Create a proper Data Model or ViewModel for your Data and use [DataBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx) to Bind the UI to your data, instead of manipulating the UI in procedural code.

Comment: I have tried this as i mentioned i get Access to path denied error.

Comment: @user3052013 then try writing to a public folder such as `C:\Users\Public\Documents` or something.

Comment: Solved - wrote in the Debug folder

Comment: had the error because you can not write directly in the root, I advise you to save all files in the user's Documents folder as is usually done.