# Adding a row to a datagrid and retrieving new values from each cell

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I need to get each value of each cell in a row. First when I add the data to the new row. The data goes away after hitting enter - however it is in my `ObservableCollection`.

I have an `ObservableCollection<object>` which I set up so that I can re-use the `Datagrid`. For instance I have an `ObservableCollection<object>` which holds multiple `CommissionOperator` (db/linq object) objects in it.  After I insert the new data into the grid, I get ,lets say, 10 `CommissionOperator` objects in my `ObservableCollection` and one `object` object in my `ObservableCollection`.

Now, I am trying to figure out how to get the value from the `Datagrid`. So I did some research and came up with this (*from a question I cant find at the moment to link*):

```
//in a class that inherits from DataGrid
     public Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGridCell GetCell( int column )
            {
                Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGridRow rowContainer = GetRow(this.SelectedIndex);

                if (rowContainer != null)
                {
                DataGridCellsPresenter presenter = GetVisualChild<DataGridCellsPresenter>( rowContainer );

                // Try to get the cell but it may possibly be virtualized.
                Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGridCell cell = (Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGridCell)presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex( column );
                if (cell == null)
                {
                    // Now try to bring into view and retreive the cell.
                    this.ScrollIntoView( rowContainer, this.Columns[column] );
                    cell = (Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGridCell)presenter.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex( column );
                }
                return cell;
            }
            return null;
        }

        public Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGridRow GetRow( int _currentRowIndex )
        {
            Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGridRow row = (Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGridRow)this.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex( _currentRowIndex );
            if (row == null)
            {
                // May be virtualized, bring into view and try again.
                this.UpdateLayout();
                this.ScrollIntoView( this.Items[_currentRowIndex] );
                row = (Microsoft.Windows.Controls.DataGridRow)this.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex( _currentRowIndex );
            }

            return row;
        }

        public static T GetVisualChild<T>( Visual parent ) where T : Visual
        {
            T child = default( T );
            int numVisuals = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount( parent );
            for (int i = 0; i < numVisuals; i++)
            {
                Visual v = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild( parent, i );
                child = v as T;
                if (child == null)
                {
                    child = GetVisualChild<T>( v );
                }
                if (child != null)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            return child;
        }
```

So I end up doing something like this:

```
((TextBox) (RGVDataSelector.GetCell(1).Content)).Text
```

Now I get an error saying that I `cannot cast TextBlock into a TexBox` and the `TextBlock.Text` is empty...

Im just trying to figure out how to get the data from the `DataGrid` when I enter data into a new row...

Here is how my `ObservableCollection` looks after adding the new row:

[image]

Here is how the `DataGrid` is during adding (just as a reference)

[image]

Here is the `DataGrid` after insert

[image]

Which I figure if I can just get the data from out of the cell that I can rebind the `DataGrid` or update the bindings or something to get it to show the right data.

Could this be happening because the data is disappearing from my `DataGrid` that I cannot actually get the data from that cell?

Comment: You don't need any of this. You don't "read data from the UI" in WPF because [UI is NOT data](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14382137/643085). Create a proper ViewModel or else read your data from your data items instead.

Comment: I have a proper ViewModel which is where my `SelectionData` `ObservableCollection` is... however I cannot get the value from of lets say `SelectionData[10]` from the pic of the `ObservableCollection` it has no properties - so I cant use reflection to get the value....

Comment: Change your collection to a strongly typed collection, not a collection of `object`. Otherwise have the ViewModel create new items, not the View. The View is not responsible for managing data items, only for showing them.

Comment: Thats the issue - I want to be able to reuse the grid with as little code as possible...by creating a strongly typed collection I wont have the option of doing this. What do you mean by have the ViewModel create new items (how can I do that without the new data being added by the user)?