# How to loop through a DataGrid and get the column values with column header?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

Here is an example of how to get column based row values in an ObservableCollection "OrderCollection":

```
Double OrderSubTotal = (Double)0;

foreach (var data in this.OrderCollection)
{
    Order orderData = (Order)data;
    //MessageBox.Show(orderData.Product.SalesPrice.ToString());
    OrderSubTotal = orderData.Product.SalesPrice;
}

this.OrderSum += OrderSubTotal;
```

Comment: You don't "loop thru a DataGrid" in WPF because [UI is NOT Data](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14382137/643085). It is strongly recommended that you create a proper DataModel / ViewModel and use proper DataBinding instead of hacking stuff out of the UI.

Comment: what for? WPF is intended to be used with DataBinding, not with horrible winforms-like hacks. There is absolutely no need for this.

Comment: simply read the values from your data model. There's no need to "read" the UI, since you already have a Bound DataModel.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataGrid.Items.Count; i++ )
{
 DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)dataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i);
 foreach (var gridColumn in dataGrid.Columns)
 {
  if(gridColumn.Header == "Something")
  {
    // Do something
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```cs
foreach(object t in PaymentDataGrid.SelectedItems)
{
    DataRowView row = t as DataRowView;
    if (row != null)
    {
        var transactionId = (int)row[0];
    }
}
```

this code worked perfectly to retrieve the specified column index for each selected row.